# Sliding Window in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

, I have to implement a sliding window algorithm on a data and further perform operation with inside the loop,below i have written the code down, the sliding window works fine for the first 500 samples where we get the correct estimates but when we change the function, the estimates seem to be wrong .

```
   clc 
   clear all
   close all
   x=rand(1,1000);
   y(2)=2;
   y(3)=4;
   y(4)=5;
   for k=4:1:501
       for i=k:1:k+10  
           y(i)=1.98*y(i-1)-1.284*y(i-2)+0.272*y(i-3)+4*x(i-1)+6*x(i-2)+8*x(i-3);
           phi(i,:)=[ -y(i-1) -y(i-2) -y(i-3) x(i-1) x(i-2) x(i-3) ];
       end
       theta = (phi'* phi)\phi'*y';
       thetaest(:,k)=theta;
   end
   for k=501:1:991
       for i=k:1:k+10  
         y(i)=1.38*y(i-1)-0.576*y(i-2)+0.068*y(i-3)+4*x(i-1)+6*x(i-2)+8*x(i-3);
         phi(i,:)=[ -y(i-1) -y(i-2) -y(i-3) x(i-1) x(i-2) x(i-3) ];
       end
       theta = (phi'* phi)\phi'*y';
       thetaest(:,k)=theta;
   end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You should pre-allocate your `y` array before doing all those assignments or you'll be really unhappy with your performance; as written, this is a Shlemiel the Painter algorithm. Do `y(991) = NaN` before your first loop to expand `y` to its final size to avoid Matlab having to reallocate the whole thing on every array iteration. And you can do `y(2:4) = [2 4 5];` for succinctness.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not cleared your variables.

In the second half you are trying to fit a single auto-regressive model to match **all** of your samples, even though the function changed halfway through.

If you restrict the samples being fitted to just the new samples it should work much better.

Change:

```
   theta = (phi'* phi)\phi'*y';
```

to

```
   phi2 = phi(501:end,:);
   y2 = y(501:end);
   theta = (phi2'* phi2)\phi2'*y2';
```

Comment: But isn't my function changing at after 500 and if I write y2=y(501:end);if I Dont specify the function y how will it get updated

Comment: I am afraid I don't really understand what you are asking.  y is an array not a function, and you already have code that computes y.  Did you try the code change I suggested?

Comment: yes when i do the changes , i am getting problem in multiplication at the bottom ,ie ; y is becoming a 1*11 ,but my phi is a 10*6 ! and i am not able to multiply !

Comment: clc 
clear all
close all
x=rand(1,1000);
y(2)=2;
y(3)=4;
y(4)=5;
for k=4:1:500
   for i=k:1:k+10  
%         y(i)=1.38*y(i-1)-0.576*y(i-2)+0.068*y(i-3)+4*x(i-1)+6*x(i-2)+8*x(i-3);
      y(i)=1.98*y(i-1)-1.284*y(i-2)+0.272*y(i-3)+4*x(i-1)+6*x(i-2)+8*x(i-3);
       phi(i,:)=[ -y(i-1) -y(i-2) -y(i-3) x(i-1) x(i-2) x(i-3) ];
         
   end
   theta = (phi'* phi)\phi'*y';
   thetaest(:,k)=theta;
end

Comment: for k=501:1:991
      for i=k:1:k+10  
           y(i)=1.38*y(i-1)-0.576*y(i-2)+0.068*y(i-3)+4*x(i-1)+6*x(i-2)+8*x(i-3);
              phi2=phi(501:end,:);
             y2=y(501:end);
   end 
    theta = (phi'* phi)\phi'*y';
   thetaest(:,k)=theta;
end

Comment: It looks like you have added the first two lines in the wrong place (before the end instead of after the end), and you haven't changed the third line to use phi2 and y2

Comment: Stick this code in a function instead of a script and all the clear-related bugs will go away because the function workspace will clean itself up automatically. Just remove the `clear all` and `close all` lines and put `function [theta,thetaest] = myfunction()` at the top of the file.